# VBA code only working for some charts

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA code for updating the secondary axes range on all graphs of a worksheet only works for some of the graphs. After the macro is run, the message "Method 'Axes' of object '_Chart' failed" is displayed, with only some of the graphs on that worksheet being updated. What's the problem here?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim objChart As ChartObject, lower As Double, upper As Double

lower = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter lower bound", Type:=1)
upper = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter upper bound", Type:=1)

For Each objChart In Sheets("Summary").ChartObjects
    With objChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
        .MinimumScale = lower
        .MaximumScale = upper
    End With
Next objChart

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what's causing the error, but you could extract the body of the loop into its own parameterized procedure *and handle runtime errors*, so that if the first iteration blows up, you're still iterating and trying with the remainder of the `ChartObjects` collection.

Comment: What types of charts do you have on that *Summary* sheet? Do they all have a secondary value axis?

Comment: I can't tell just from the code, but try adding `debug.print objChart.name` inside the loop and step through the code with F8. See which charts get updated and which don't, maybe there is something different about those who don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `ChartObject` doesn't have a secondary axis, accessing it will raise an error. I couldn't figure out a way to reproduce your exact error, but as I said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109429/vba-code-only-working-for-some-charts#comment65566444_39109429), extracting a procedure and handling runtime errors should at least help diagnosing the problem and making the loop iterate all charts:

```
Public Sub UpdateSummarySheetChartAxes()

    Dim lower As Double
    lower = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter lower bound", Type:=1)

    Dim upper As Double        
    upper = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter upper bound", Type:=1)

    Dim objChart As ChartObject
    For Each objChart In Sheets("Summary").ChartObjects
        UpdateChartAxes objChart, lower, upper
    Next objChart

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateChartAxes(ByVal objChart As ChartObject, ByVal lower As Double, ByVal upper As Double)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    With objChart.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
        .MinimumScale = lower
        .MaximumScale = upper
    End With
CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
CleanFail:
    Debug.Print "Failed updating axes for chart '" & objChart.Name & "'. Message: " & Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Beautiful. The problem is indeed those graphs without a secondary axis. This is a great way to diagnose problems in general as well. Will accept as answer once I'm allowed to do so, many thanks!

Comment: `If .Axes.Count > 2 Then` --> has a secondary y-axis (assuming there arte never secondary x-axes...)